# Changing RAZOR edit box in view to drop down box

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to change the following to a drop down box but am having very little success:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.BillStatus)
```

I have defined a list of type string (which has all of the two variables Active and Inactive) but how do I set this as the BillStatus which belongs to my model as above? This is on the scaffolded create view for my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `DropDownList` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", Model.BillStatus.Select(Function(x) New SelectListItem() With { .Text = x, .Value = x }))
```

And if your view model already has a property to harbor the selected value (of type string) you could use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor` helper

```
@Html.DropDownList(Function(model) model.Status, Model.BillStatus.Select(Function(x) New SelectListItem() With { .Text = x, .Value = x }))
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here but then how how exactly do I pass the list to the dropdown box using the first implementation. If I add it on its own I get the following: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: In my answer I assumed that the `BillStatus` property on your model is a `List(Of String)` containing the values you want to be shown in the dropdown and populated by the controller action rendering this view. So inside your controller action you simply add the elements to this list before passing the model to the view.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of Html.EditorFor does not support dropdown lists.

Instead, use Html.DropDownListFor

Comment: Ive tried that but how then do I let my view know that that value belongs to the BillStatus for the model?